# Did Boba-Fett ever have children (or clones) of his own?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, character-development

Given that his 'father', Jango, raised him as a clone-son and likely wouldn't have the normal parent-child relationship, I would be curious to see if he had a child of his own, and if the child would be naturally-conceived.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the EU, Boba married [Sintas Vel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sintas_Vel) in 16 BBY and had the child [Ailyn Vel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ailyn_Vel) naturally.

Comment: and Ailyn had a daughter herself.  Boba's a grandpoppy.

Answer (score 0):

Speculative answer for current post-2012 canon:

**Maybe**

[image: canon Vel?!?]

A new character that could fit being Boba Fett’s daughter and a canon riff of “Ailyn Vel” type character is introduced in “Throne,” the official *Book of Boba Fett* Special Look trailer (0:46s mark)

Comment: Who is this and where are they from?

Comment: New character from the latest Book of Boba Fett trailer, “Throne” that just dropped.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know there was a new trailer. Maybe add that to your answer though? To add credibility

Answer (score -1):

yes I think Boba does because I have found a image on the internet with him and a girl with a baby also there are some sences in the movie were boba sounds like his wife, son, or daughter are in danger by darth vader because knowing how bobas father was and how he is from star wars the clone wars he sounds and act like a guy how would be agaisnt the empire and the rebels and make is own team like deathwatch

Comment: Welcome to Sci Fi and Fantasy SE, do you have any canonical sources that you can use to reference your image or ideas from, or are they just fan-art? We like to look for answers which are strongly supported with facts!